# "Two double bacon cheeseburgers" or "two bacon double cheeseburgers"?

Tags: word-order

I guess "bacon" acts like an adjective here, or, more correctly, it's probably an attributive. So which order is correct? I tried googling; "two bacon double cheeseburgers" yielded more results (28 800 000 vs 9 060 000). Nevertheless, I am so curious I wish to know which grammar rule applies here. One minor problem is that electronic translators (machines) sometimes treat the word "double" in "two bacon double cheeseburgers" as a verb. It's obviously wrong, of course.

Comment: There's no "rule of grammar" here - just basic ***semantics***. Do you want double the normal amount of bacon, or of cheese[burger]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attributive nouns order Vs. Adjectives order](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183887/attributive-nouns-order-vs-adjectives-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply the name used by a popular fast food franchise.

There are two burgers, each with cheese (hence "double cheeseburger") and bacon as an extra. You might say "double cheeseburger with bacon" But the name of the product is "Bacon Double Cheeseburger". There isn't a rule being applied in a consistent way.

Comment: I would want to know whether I was ordering two regular cheeseburgers, each with 'double bacon' (twice the usual amount of bacon) or two double-sized cheeseburgers, each with the regular amount of bacon, or something else.

Comment: You look at the pictures of of the food, since that sort of place usually puts pictures of the food. Like I said, it's just a name. After all "cheeseburger" is a strange mixed up formation. The etymology is just weird